# IIS6 - Page not found redirect to different website

Tags: iis, redirect

running IIS6 and am seeking guidance on how to accomplish a specific goal.

I have a website e.g. www.xyz.com that I want to archive and host on a different URL e.g. archive.xyz.com, and a new website will be hosted on the original URL xyz.com.

I would like 'page not founds' on the new website (xyz.com) to redirect from xyz.com to archive.xyz.com, modifying the URL from xyz.com/somepage to archive.xyz.com/somepage and directing the browser to that URL.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Nobody should use the end-of-life IIS 6 any more, and Microsoft has removed all relevant information from its sites. For IIS 7 and above, learn URL Rewrite module and it can fulfill the requirements.

Comment: It is in extended support. IIS 6.2. I couldn't find how rewrite would handle page not found as a condition or some such.

Comment: There is no IIS 6.2. We call that IIS 8, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#History Instead of waiting for 404, you should write rewrite rules to actively redirect. But if you really want to handle 404, use custom error pages.